# Rails 5: Nil error in the first argument of a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm quite new with rails so excuse my ignorance. 
I have an homepage with a view of astronomic observations and I want to put in the same page the view of the outings that the observatory organize.
Since I can't append two views in the same page I tryed to pass the second view as a partial but I get an error

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

So I though it was a problem of variables and tryed to pass the local variable of the partial but nothing changed.
So how do I pass a variable of @outing to the partial outings/_index.html.erb which will be visualized in the view of observative_sessions

I defined  `@outing=Outing.new` in outings_controller which is the controller for the view outings

In app > views > observative_sessions I have the index.html.erb with

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id = "observative_sessions">
...
</div>
<%= render 'outings/index', :outings => @outing %>
```

In app > views > outings I put an _index.html.erb

```
<%= render 'outings/new_modal' %>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
...
<tbody>
  <% @outings.each do |outing| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

The _new_modal.html.erb calls the _form.html.erb

```
<%= render 'outings/form' %>
```

And then the form

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @outing do |f| %>
 <%= f.date_field :day, label: 'Giorno:' %>
 <%= f.text_field :location, label: 'Luogo:' %>
 <%= f.time_field :time, label: 'Ora:' %>
 <%= f.submit 'Aggiorna' %>
<% end %>
```

I get the error in the first line of the form with @outing.
If I put the view in a page alone everything work but not with the partial.
So what did I do wrong?

Thank you in advance for all the help.

Comment: How and where are you defining `@outing`?

Comment: In the outings_controller `@outing = Outing.new`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `@outing` variable to all forms those are using `@outing` variable.

Change the line of rendering `_new_modal.html.erb` partial like this

`<%= render 'outings/new_modal', outing: outings %>`

Then change the line of rendering `_form.html.erb` like this

`<%= render 'outings/form', outing: outing %>`

And finally change the actual form like this

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for outing do |f| %>
  <%= f.date_field :day, label: 'Giorno:' %>
  <%= f.text_field :location, label: 'Luogo:' %>
  <%= f.time_field :time, label: 'Ora:' %>
  <%= f.submit 'Aggiorna' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you provide the error message a bit in details? may be in screenshot?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to save a file still I get this error ![rails nil argument error](http://i66.tinypic.com/21muiwo.jpg)

Comment: Could you please provide the full code of  `index.html.erb`, `outings/_index.html.erb`, `_new_modal.html.erb ` and `outings_controller`. May be by creating a gist https://gist.github.com/?

Answer (score 0):

In app > views > observative_sessions I have the index.html.erb with

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id = "observative_sessions">
...
</div>
<%= render partial: 'outings/index', locals: {outing: @outing} %>
```

In app > views > outings I put an _index.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'outings/new_modal',locals: {outing: outing} %>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
...
<tbody>
  <% @outings.each do |outing| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

The _new_modal.html.erb calls the _form.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'outings/form', locals: {outing: outing} %>
```

Then in your form use the local outing variable:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for outing do |f| %>
  <%= f.date_field :day, label: 'Giorno:' %>
  <%= f.text_field :location, label: 'Luogo:' %>
  <%= f.time_field :time, label: 'Ora:' %>
  <%= f.submit 'Aggiorna' %>
<% end %>
```